# How to get data from array based on a specific value

Tags: c#, arrays, list, indexof

I'm working in C# and I have troubles with importing data.

I have a txt document which contains data:

```
S/1234 001 2583 2 0 3 
S/1234 002 4323 2 0 3
S/1234 003 4583 2 0 3
S/2582 001 8745 3 0 4
S/2582 002 8254 3 0 4
S/2582 003 658T 3 0 4
S/2582 004 8785 3 0 4
```

I imported this document in a list:

```
S/1234 2583
S/1234 4323
S/1234 4583
S/2582 8745
S/2582 8254
S/2582 658T
S/2582 8785
```

And code looks like this:

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@fileLocal);
 List<string> whole_line = new List<string>();    
 List<string> only_first_column = new List<string>();    
 foreach (string line in lines)
    {
     string[] linee=line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     whole_line.Add(linee[0].ToString()+" "+linee[2].ToString());
     only_first_column.Add(linee[0].ToString());
    }
```

Now, my question is, how can I get the data and store it in two arrays/or list by values S/1234 and S/2582?

I'm trying to get array #1:

> `2583 4323 4583`

and array #2:

> `8745 8254 658T 8785`

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will only have these 2 values S/1234  and S/2582 you can do it ine a simple way.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@fileLocal);
List<string> s1234 = new List<string>();    
List<string> s2582 = new List<string>();  

foreach (string line in lines)
{
        string[] linee = line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if(linee[0].ToString() == "S/1234"){
            s1234.Add(linee[2].ToString()); 
        }else{
            s2582.Add(linee[2].ToString()); 
        }
}
```

Keep in mind this a very basic solution wit the assumption that you just want to handle these 2 keys, if your goal is more generic it will not work

Comment: it is generic, it wont work and I'm not using linq :(

Comment: If it is generic, you need to update your question to really explain waht you  are looking for.

Comment: Data S/1234 and S/2582 are different - in the next txt file it could be S/2584, S/6985 and A/5874.

Comment: Your idea and solution really helped me, thank you very much :))!!

Answer (score 0):

Using linq:

```
var groups = lines.GroupBy(x => x.Split(' ').First());

string[] array1 = groups.Where(x => x.Key == "S/1234")
                        .SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.Split(' ')[2]).ToArray();

string[] array2 = groups.Where(x => x.Key == "S/2582")
                        .SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x.Split(' ')[2]).ToArray();
```